# Electron window not showing up after successfull build

Tags: node.js, electron, electron-builder

This week I got into electron and I have built my own simple project. I want to build it into an executable file. I have followed [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDhA5ti-x20) with building an electron project. The build goes as it should.

```
    loaded configuration  file=package.json ("build" field)
    description is missed in the package.json  appPackageFile=C:\Users\evalo\Desktop\Desktop\electron\02-nekton\package.json
    writing effective config  file=dist\builder-effective-config.yaml
    packaging       platform=win32 arch=x64 electron=16.0.5 appOutDir=dist\win-unpacked
    building        target=nsis file=dist\nekton Setup 1.0.1.exe archs=x64 oneClick=false perMachine=false
    building block map  blockMapFile=dist\nekton Setup 1.0.1.exe.blockmap
```

After that, I ran the installer and installed the app without any problem and launched the shortcut, which had been generated on the desktop. The main window didn't show up but in Task Manager I could see that the application is running (3 times actually after one launch, don't know why)

[image: Task Manager screenshot of 3 instances of my app]

Content of my package.json file, if it helps:

```
{
  "name": "nekton",
  "produktName": "nekton",
  "version": "1.0.1",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron .",
    "build": "electron-builder"
  },
  "build": {
    "asar": true,
    "appId": "nekton",
    "win": {
      "target": [
        "nsis"
      ],
      "icon": "nekton.ico"
    },
    "nsis": {
      "oneClick": false,
      "installerIcon": "nekton.ico",
      "uninstallerIcon": "nekton.ico",
      "uninstallDisplayName": "Nekton-uninstaller",
      "license": "license.md",
      "allowToChangeInstallationDirectory": true
    }
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "electron-store": "^8.0.1",
    "wallpaper": "^6.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^16.0.5",
    "electron-builder": "^22.14.5"
  }
}
```

One thing, which might affect this behaviour is that I hadn't saved electron as dev dependency before I started working on the app. I just installed it: `npm i electron`. When I tried to build it gave my error with a hint to move electron into dev dependencies. So I ran:

```
npm uninstall electron
npm i --save-dev electron
```

Tried to launch the app with: `npm start` and all worked flawlessly. So I assumed that this didn't affect the project.

**Edit:**
-----------------

I made and build an app to show static HTML files in the main window with the same build configuration. All worked flawlessly. The app launched and behaved as expected. So I have manually created a new project and copied the content of each file to the project which has been built before without error. I have encountered the same problem. The app works fine with `npm start`, builds, installs. After installation is complete the app 'runs' but without a window. I think there might be a run error, which would be logged into the terminal in vscode at the start and the application is halted. Is there a way I can see the terminal for my app after it has been installed?